# Making a callback inside a callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

I have a problem with an async operation. I need to know when my table is generated. But the table is generated from information from the database fetched via ajax.

This would be my start point, where I need to know that the data are fetched and the table is generated:

```
generateTable(function(r){

});
```

Here I fetch the information from DB and send them to the callback function

```
function getRepairBook(callback) {
            $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                url: "x",
                success: function(response){
                    callback(response);
                },
                error: function(response){

                }
            });
        }
```

here I need a callback for the callback function. But I have no clue how to do that:

```
function generateTable(callback) {

//callback of AJAX
   getRepairBook(function (response) {  //, callback

     console.log(response);
     $('#repTable >tbody').html("");

     var trHTML = '';
     $.each(response, function (i, item) {

       //...
       //build table
     });
     $('#repTable >tbody').append(trHTML);
     //need a callback of this callback function
     //callback();
   });

   callback();
}
```

Comment: Do you have to use callbacks? Are you able to use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) or [async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)?

Comment: This is why we invented Promises. Add the second callback to ajax call of the first: `success: function(response){callback(response, otherCallback);}` and `getRepairBook( function(response), otherCallback)` You can nest as deep as you want, but end up with the pryamid of doom. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can chain [JQuery deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) objects.
They work this way:

```js
function foo() {
  // initialize the deferred
  var dfd = $.Deferred();
  
  // resolve the deferred after 2 sec
  setTimeout(function() {
    dfd.resolve();
  }, 2000);
  
  // return the promise
  return dfd.promise();
}

function bar() {
  var dfd = $.Deferred();  
  // resolve the deferred after 1 sec
  setTimeout(function() {
    dfd.resolve();
  }, 1000);
  return dfd.promise();
}

$(function() {      
  var dfd = foo();
  // when foo has been resolved
  dfd.then(function() {
    alert('foo has been resolved');
    var dfd2 = bar();
    // when bar has been resolved
    dfd2.then(function() {
      alert('bar has been resolved');
    });
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The $.ajax call returns a promise, so you can chain the resolution of this promise with the next action/function you want to execute.